# Mudar texto do input type=file com o nome do arquivo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou fazendo um projeto em asp.net MVC 5, e preciso que o texto do meu input do tipo 'file' mude para o nome do arquivo ao carregá-lo. 
Ocultei o input para ele ser acionado ao  clicar no `label` em CSS conforme abaixo:

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="fupload" class="control-label label-bordered">Clique aqui para escolher um arquivo</label>
     <input type="file" id="fupload" name="fupload" class="fupload form-control" />
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="file"] { 
   display: none; 
}

.label-bordered {
   border: 1px solid #cecece;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Ficou assim:

[image: Input estilizado]

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue um exemplo simples, para que você faça uma adaptação.

> Documento

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="fupload" class="control-label label-bordered">Clique aqui para escolher um arquivo</label>
     <div class="nomeArquivo"></div>
     <input type="file" id="fupload" name="fupload" class="fupload form-control" />
 </div>
```

> JavaScript + JQUERY

```
$(function () {
    $('#fupload').change(function() {
         $('.nomeArquivo').html('<b>Arquivo Selecionado:</b>' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Muito bom! Eu fiz assim:
                var fileName = $('#fupload').val().split('\\').pop();
                $('#label-fupload').text("'" + fileName + "' carregado e pronto para enviar!");

Comment: Boa, eu iria postar algo assim mas pensei... deixe a lógica dele trabalhar hehehehe

Comment: hahaha Obrigado por isso! As vezes só precisamos de um 'empurrãozinho'.